# Understand the utility of Adapter Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

Well, i'm studying about Adapter Design Pattern but i'm felling confused about a example i saw in book. The scenario is the following:

I have a AudioPlayer class that implements MediaPlayer interface that can play only MP3 Music. See:

```
public interface MediaPlayer {
   public void play(String audioType, String fileName);
}


public class AudioPlayer implements MediaPlayer {

    @Override
    public void play(String audioType, String fileName) {
        if (audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("mp3")){
            System.out.println("Playing "+fileName+" ...");
        }else{
            System.err.println("Unsupported Format");
        }       
    }

}
```

Now, I have another third library with more features, like play MP4 and VCL format. This is the interface and classes (imagine that i can't change anything in this third library, is just .class file):

```
public interface AdvancedMediaPlayer {  
   public void playVlc(String fileName);
   public void playMp4(String fileName);
}

public class VlcPlayer implements AdvancedMediaPlayer{
   @Override
   public void playVlc(String fileName) {
      System.out.println("Playing vlc file. Name: "+ fileName);     
   }

   @Override
   public void playMp4(String fileName) {
      //do nothing
   }
}

public class Mp4Player implements AdvancedMediaPlayer{

   @Override
   public void playVlc(String fileName) {
      //do nothing
   }

   @Override
   public void playMp4(String fileName) {
      System.out.println("Playing mp4 file. Name: "+ fileName);     
   }
}
```

So, the book suggest the i should create a MediaAdapter class that implements MediaPlayer and uses AdvancedMediaPlayer, like this:

```
public class MediaAdapter implements MediaPlayer {

   AdvancedMediaPlayer advancedMusicPlayer;

   public MediaAdapter(String audioType){
      if(audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("vlc") ){
         advancedMusicPlayer = new VlcPlayer();         
      } else if (audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")){
         advancedMusicPlayer = new Mp4Player();
      } 
   }

   @Override
   public void play(String audioType, String fileName) {
      if(audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("vlc")){
         advancedMusicPlayer.playVlc(fileName);
      }else if(audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")){
         advancedMusicPlayer.playMp4(fileName);
      }
   }
}
```

And after i'll use this MediaApter in AudioPlayer class to add support to another formats, like this:

```
public class AudioPlayer implements MediaPlayer {
   MediaAdapter mediaAdapter; 

   @Override
   public void play(String audioType, String fileName) {        

      //inbuilt support to play mp3 music files
      if(audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("mp3")){
         System.out.println("Playing mp3 file. Name: "+ fileName);          
      } 
      //mediaAdapter is providing support to play other file formats
      else if(audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("vlc") 
         || audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")){
         mediaAdapter = new MediaAdapter(audioType);
         mediaAdapter.play(audioType, fileName);
      }
      else{
         System.out.println("Invalid media. "+
            audioType + " format not supported");
      }
   }   
}
```

But i really don't understand why so much work to make a simple thing. My suggestion is delete MediaAdapter class and make this with AudioPlayer class:

```
public class AudioPlayer implements MediaPlayer {


   @Override
   public void play(String audioType, String fileName) {        

      //inbuilt support to play mp3 music files
      if(audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("mp3")){
         System.out.println("Playing mp3 file. Name: "+ fileName);          
      } 
      //mediaAdapter is providing support to play other file formats
      else if(audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("vlc")){
         new VclPlayer().playVlc(fileName);         
      }else if (audioType.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")){
          new Mp4Player().playMp4(fileName);
      }
      else{
         System.out.println("Invalid media. "+
            audioType + " format not supported");
      }
   }   
}
```

So, i need understand why use MediaAdapter when i can discard this option and use VclPlayer or Mp4Player direct in AudioPlayer class.

Comment: Adapter are used, where the original design is flawed and you are not allowed, or it is too time consuming to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to decouple as much as possible.
`AudioPlayer` should not know the implementations of `VclPlayer` or `Mp4Player`.

`AudioPlayer` should only worry about playing the file (calling the `play` method of the adapter).

**How** it will be played should not be a matter to worry for `AudioPlayer`.

Imagine that `Mp4Player` is changed, and now accepts a new constructor argument. It is highly possible that `AudioPlayer` will not know how to provide this argument. That's why `MediaAdapter` exists, this is the class that should worry about configuring the players.

You see now, that you are giving each class a specific purpose.

- The `VlcPlayer` and `Mp4Player` know how to play an specific file.
- The `MediaAdapter` knows how to initialize and configure these players and ***which one to call*** when given a file to play.
- The `AudioPlayer` will be a bridge between the user and the `MediaAdapter`. It will take the file and provide it to the adapter.

Comment: I think that i'm finally understand the concept. Declouping as much as possible i avoid the rewrite of code. Example: If i use Mp4Player direct in all points of project and tomorrow the constructor change i'll need change this points to acept the new constructor, if i use Adapter i just change the adapter. Right ? The Adapter is the bridge between A million of music format players and the GENERIC PLAYER.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give you a simpler example. Have you ever worked with socket wrenches?  You know that some sockets plug in directly to the wrench, while others need an **adapter** if you ever want to use that socket with **THAT** wrench.  Of course, you can always go to a hardware store and buy a wrench that could fit that socket without the adapter. But, do you really want to pay that much for an additional wrench for just that one socket?  Probably not. An "adapter" is much cheaper than the wrench.

Take that example and apply it to Software.  You have an interface that has already been defined and used; so it is proven to work.  Your development team has incorporated that interface into their code.  Now you have a utility that is incompatible with that interface.  What would you do? Or better yet, what do you think your boss would want you to do? Build a whole new interface for just that utility, or build an "adapter" to take full advantage of code that has already been written?

This is the versatility of an Adapter pattern.  In the example you provided, you have Media Player (interface) that has already been incorporated and code written to that contract that is proven to work.  Today, this media players plays MP3 files.  Tomorrow, some guy creates a new media format, and you want to be able to play it with the Media Player that you already have.  So, instead of writing a whole new Media Player, you build an adapter class that uses the media player and bridges the gap between the interface and the new library so it could comply with the contact.

Comment: i appreciate your help, was much usefull for my understanding.